# MapKit default zoom

Tags: swift, mapkit

For some reason my market won't zoom to the local region.  In fact, it does not change the zoom no matter what I change.  Am I loading it in the wrong part of the code, or am I missing something else?  Any help is appreciated.

My code is:

```
@IBOutlet var here: MKMapView!

var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
var selectedItem: String?
func locationManager
    (manager: CLLocationManager!,didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!,
    fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!){
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest


        var region = self.here.region as MKCoordinateRegion

        self.here.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.0144927536
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.0144927536

}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you need to set the lat and long BEFORE you set the region. The setRegion function is what zooms in on a certain part, and the level of the zoom depends on your span. Here's an example of a map that zooms.

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.075, 0.075)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long), span: span)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Comment: What are your variables for lat and long?

Comment: They can be anything really. The easiest way I've found to get lat and long data is to use Google Maps. Just google whatever you want and then right click on the location on the map and choose "What's Here?" and it will show the lat and long.